# How related amount with currency

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I want to related amount line with currency for create analytic entries.

```
@api.multi
def action_test(self):
    for order in self:
        for line in order.order_line:
            amount = (self.credit or 0.0) - (self.debit or 0.0)
            if line.account_analytic_id:
                vals_line= {
                    'name': line.name,
                    'date': order.date_order,
                    'account_id': line.account_analytic_id.id,
                    'tag_ids': [(6, 0, line.analytic_tag_ids.ids)],
                    'unit_amount': line.product_qty,
                    'product_id': line.product_id and line.product_id.id or False,
                    'amount': order.company_currency_id.with_context(date=order.date_order or fields.Date.context_today(self)).compute(amount, line.account_analytic_id.currency_id) if line.account_analytic_id.currency_id else amount,
                    #'general_account_id': self.account_id.id,
                    #'ref': order.ref,
                    'move_id': line.id,
                    #'user_id': order.invoice_id.user_id.id or self._uid,
                }
                self.env['account.analytic.line'].create(vals_line)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want return amount then add a blank field(float or integer) similar to amount field and try that:

```
vals_line = {
'amount' : line.amount
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 vals_line= {
     'currency_id': line.currency_id
      }
```

Comment: Hi, how to compare two lines purchase lines and invoice lines